# How do we check whether a column has any letters or not

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to use a query like:

```
select * from test
```

where data in the column has alphanumeric values.

e.g. if column `rollno` has values like 20,30,40,50C,30F, then how do I find the values which have 50C and 30F types of values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your data is varchar2 and you want to validate it against a pattern, you can use the [REGEXP_LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) function

For instance, to select the fields that are digits followed by non digit characters, you can use:

```
select * from table
where regexp_like(field, '^\d+\D+$');
```

From your list, this will return 50C and 30F

Answer (score -1):

You can use ISNUMERIC  in SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT *
FROM    myTabet
WHERE   ISNUMERIC (myColumn) = 0
```